# 'be + formed' or 'to be + formed'

Tags: sentence-structure

The Secretary of State ordered that a committee **be formed** to investigate the matter.

Why 'be formed' is used instead of 'to be formed'?

Is it because of 'That-clause'?

Comment: No, it because of how certain verbs work: order, recommend, advise, suggest (there may be others, I haven't looked it up). And, by the way, the that is not really needed. She recommended a bed be purchased for the new wing. He advised a poem be read for the occasion. They suggested a party be held for the new couple.

Comment: "He ordered a committee _to_ be formed" OR "He ordered _that_ a committee be formed".

Comment: "He ordered a committee be formed immediately". Or advise, recommended, suggest. If you leave out that it is still grammatical.

Comment: When the relative pronoun is the subject of a relative clause, it must be included. Here, the that is not the subject of a relative clause.

Comment: I just searched....the sentence is in subjunctive mood that's why 'to' is left while making passive.........is it correct?

Comment: It is not called subjunctive anymore. In any case, all those verbs I have you work the same way.

Comment: @Lambie okay....thanku

Comment: @Lambie....U have written 'I have u'....r u saying 'I have given u'?

Comment: Of course, it's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good opportunity to point out that other verbs trigger this be passive form also.

The Secretary of State ordered (that) a committee be formed to investigate the matter.

The Secretary of State advised (that) a committee be formed to investigate the matter.

The Secretary of State recommended (that) a committee be formed to investigate the matter.

The Sectary of  State suggested (that) a committee be formed to investigate the matter.

Be aware that in the third person singular, there  would be **no s** in the present and be for the passive form.

- He recommends the boy **leave** early for school.
- He recommends **the boy be left alone**. [passive form]

Answer (score -1):

Well, if there were a verb that requires *to infitinive* , that would be "to be formed":

He ordered to be formed - he ordered the committee to be formed.

But, *that* is a clue there. You are not wrong. And if you check *subjunctive* you will understand it better [Collins Dictionary](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-subjunctive)

Comment: Then I would advise you to check link I provided : The clause containing the subjunctive is linked to the main clause with that.

Comment: Well, as a newbie here I cannot comment anywhere but I must say that I am bewildered by the posts of Lambie. It looks like s/he invents some grammar by herself/himself. Can you please explain what that means?: It is not called subjunctive anymore.. Is it Present Continuous from now on? Feeling shocked.

Comment: It definitely looks like that you did not understand my sentence. I used "clue" for "that" as it is also used in subjunctive and RADS got a point there. Please do not forget, being a native speaker will never and never let you know English grammar in an academic way. "He ordered to be formed" was an example, because, if you looked at the title of the question, you could clearly see that!

Comment: Dear Lambie, I really do not understand why you don't want to get it. It's so simple. "To be formed" is used with a "to infitinive passive form". That's why I mentioned it. That's why I wrote that sentence. It's really simple, I believe. When my students ask the same question I tell them the same thing: "He doesn't want to be sent" is a to infinitive passive example like "to be formed". And you said something funnier: It's not called subjunctive anymore. Then, what is it called? Can you please explain and enlighten us? A subject in grammar without a title?

Comment: The verb I used there was not the point. I was trying to show the concept. Because the answer of the question is not so difficult and it could be explained in a simple way. And s/he found it out: "I just searched....the sentence is in subjunctive mood that's why 'to' is left while making passive.........is it correct?" Yes, it is! That's all. And I shared the link there. Period goes here. If you need to make a list of verbs, for any topic, if the student needs it, then you can do it / add it later, as a detailed answer. Anyway, my answer was correct and it didn't deserve to be voted down.